# How to restrict values in a Django DecimalField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have an Order model with a `price` field. I'd like to have my form restrict this field to values between 0.0 and 1.0, but I don't want the actual model restricted as such.

Currently my form code is:

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('stock', 'order', 'volume', 'price')
```

A dropdown input would be ideal, but I have no idea how to accomplish that through Django forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    price = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PRICE_CHOICES)
```

Where `PRICE_CHOICES` is a tuple of tuples in the form of:

```
PRICE_CHOICES = (
    (value, display),
    (value, display),
    ...
)
```

Actually since you're dealing with a linear progression, you can even use some syntax sugar:

```
price_choices = [('%.2f' % (x*0.1), '$%.2f' % (x*0.1)) for x in range(0,11)]
```

The only difference is I threw a dollar sign in front of the display value, but you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is to, in my init method of the form modify the auto generated field by appending a validator to it that checks to see that the value of the form field is in the range you want.

```
Class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
   def __init__(*arg, **kwargs):
    super(OrderForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['price'].validators = [valid_price_range]


def valid_price_range(value):
    if value < 0 or value > 1:
       throw ValidationError(u'%s is not between 0 and 1' % value)
```